# Lua 'plain' string.gsub

Tags: string, parsing, lua, gsub, lua-patterns

I've hit s small block with string parsing.  I have a string like:

```
footage/down/temp/cars_[100]_upper/cars_[100]_upper.exr
```

and I'm having difficulty using gsub to delete a portion of the string.  Normally I would do this

```
lineA = footage/down/temp/cars_[100]_upper/cars_[100]_upper.exr
lineB = footage/down/temp/cars_[100]_upper/
newline = lineA:gsub(lineB, "")
```

which would normally give me 'cars_[100]_upper.exr'

The problem is that gsub doesn't like the [] or other special characters in the string and unlike string.find gsub doesn't have the option of using the 'plain' flag to cancel pattern searching.

I am not able to manually edit the lines to include escape characters for the special characters as I'm doing file a file comparison script.

Any help to get from `lineA` to newline using `lineB` would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Taking from page 181 of Programming in Lua 2e:

> The magic characters are:
>
> ```
> ( ) . % + - * ? [ ] ^ $
> ```
>
> The character '%' works as an escape
>   for these magic characters.

So, we can just come up with a simple function to escape these magic characters, and apply it to your input string (`lineB`):

```
function literalize(str)
    return str:gsub("[%(%)%.%%%+%-%*%?%[%]%^%$]", function(c) return "%" .. c end)
end

lineA = "footage/down/temp/cars_[100]_upper/cars_[100]_upper.exr"

lineB = literalize("footage/down/temp/cars_[100]_upper/")

newline = lineA:gsub(lineB, "")

print(newline)
```

Which of course prints: `cars_[100]_upper.exr`.

Comment: Another (probably faster) way to write literalize: `str:gsub("[%(%)%.%%%+%-%*%?%[%]%^%$]", "%%%0")`

Comment: EXCELLENT approach. Side note: yeah lua patterns are in the way a lot of the time. 'Powerful'. How about useful?

Answer (score 4):

You may use another approach like:

```
local i1, i2 = lineA:find(lineB, nil, true)
local result = lineA:sub(i2 + 1)
```

Comment: Just put that in a loop until find returns non-nil to match that gsub replaces all occurrences of the pattern.

Comment: This doesn't work either, because also in string.find magic characters are considered as such (see next answer below).

Comment: Passing true as the forth parameter (self, pattern, init, plain) makes the function ignore magic characters in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can also escape punctuation in a text string, str, using:

`str:gsub ("%p", "%%%0")`